# Check if the Registered User Mail Address is already available in database or not

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, data-access-layer

My stored procedure code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_GetRegisterUsers]
   @Email varchar(50)
AS
   IF EXISTS(SELECT EmailId FROM RegTable WHERE EmailId = @Email)
   BEGIN
       declare @result varchar
       Select @result 'E-Mail ID Already Exists'
   END
   ELSE
   BEGIN
        print 'Successfully entered the E-Mail Address'
   END
```

Here the stored procedure gets executed successfully.

I want this result to use in my C# MVC application, I also have used a WCF service and data access layer.

Can anyone please let me know the code?

`Register.cshtml` btn design code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Register" />
    </div>
</div>
```

WCF service code:

```
public class Registration : IRegistration
{
    public void Register(string email, string fullName, string password)
    {
        //WCF Web.Config Connection string is passed
        string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnStringDb1"].ToString();
        RegistrationDAL registrationDal = new RegistrationDAL();
        registrationDal.Register(email, fullName, password, conStr);
    }

    //Create a new method to check if the user exists in the database
    public void ChkRegUser(string email)
    {
        string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnStringDb1"].ToString();
        RegistrationDAL registrationDal = new RegistrationDAL();
        registrationDal.GetUser(email, conStr);
    }
}
```

DAL Code:

```
public void GetUser(string email, string connectionString)
{
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_GetRegisterUsers", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", email);
            //cmd.Parameters.GetType.email()
            conn.Open();
            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                string Return = (string)cmd.Parameters["@email"].Value;
                //if(email == null)
                //{

                //}
                //else
                //{

                //}
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
}
```

Can anyone please assist?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Move the message in your application (eg. localization). Stored procedure can return true or false.

Answer (score 0):

There is simple way of returning value form sp.try this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_GetRegisterUsers]
   @Email varchar(50)
AS
   IF EXISTS(SELECT EmailId FROM RegTable WHERE EmailId = @Email)
   BEGIN

       Select 'E-Mail ID Already Exists'
   END
   ELSE
   BEGIN
        SELECT 'Successfully entered the E-Mail Address'
   END
```

and code behind file

```
public void GetUser(string email, string connectionString)
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_GetRegisterUsers", conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();

                param = cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
               param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
               param.Value = email;


                conn.Open();
                try
                {
                    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    String returnValue = String.Empty;
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                       returnValue =Convert.ToString( reader.GetValue(0));
                       break;
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(returnValue);

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```